# Returning attribute called "name" in BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I would need to return the value of child called "name" in an XML file. The default usage only returns the name of the tag (as the .name seems to be a BS4 function, that returns the tag's name:

```
for e in eventSoup.find_all('event'):
    print(e.name)

# event
```

Is there a way to return the the actual value of the tag?

edit: The XML is structured like this:

```
<event id="7">
<def_id>7</def_id>
<name>Event name</name>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find`.

```
Events = soup.find_all("event")

for Event in Events:
    NameChild = Event.find("name")
    print (NameChild.text)
```

Outputs:

> Event name

Comment: Your code is not using pep-8 conventions. Variables in python are not supposed to be camelcase. Please edit it.

Comment: @LaraChicharo PEP8 is the last thing to take care of. Do not PEP8 other people.

Answer (score 0):

you need .`text` property.

eg:

```
for e in eventSoup.find_all('event'):
    nameTag = e.find('name')
    print(nameTag.text)
```